# Can SQL injection be prevented with just addslashes(string)?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does mysql_real_escape_string() do that addslashes() doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534742/what-does-mysql-real-escape-string-do-that-addslashes-doesnt)

If not, I have used mysql_escape_string, and it adds characters to the words like \r\n, and I don't want that..

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` won't add anything to the final data. If that happens for you, start a separate question about that, there is probably something else going on

Comment: If you're having problems with mysql_real_escape_string() adding stuff, make sure Magic Quotes is turned OFF.

Comment: It's in your php.ini file: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not safe.  Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.  It shouldn't add anything beyond what it takes to escape the string.

http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string

This applies to other databases too: use the extension-specific escape function.

Comment: @MichaelTontchev It makes sure that everything is escaped for a SQL string in the proper way, not just quotes.  There's a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473047

Answer (score 3):

No, `addslashes` is not good enough. `mysql_escape_string` is not necessarily good enough. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Whether you like what it adds or not doesn't matter, it only escapes characters to make sure the query syntax is valid. If this gets in the way of what you're doing, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to prevent SQL injection is to use prepared statement with either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 2):

You also have the option of using the mysqli functions and Prepared Statements. This largely avoids the problem in the first place because all quotes are considered part of the data.