# Does htmlspecialchars protect this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, get

I got a `$_GET` and users are able to send the `$_GET` string to the MySQL, so quick question:

Is this query:

`mysql_query("SELECT XX FROM ZZ WHERE YY %LIKE% " . htmlspecialchars($_get['string']) . ";");`

enough to be safe? or I should add something more than `htmlspecialchars()` to be safe?

Thank you in advance for all replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unsafe.**

Trivial example data that even *shows htmlspecialchars doing "it's thing"* -- it's just *the wrong "thing"*.

```
1;DROP TABLE all_your_precious_data--&
```

Happy coding.

---

Solution: Use placeholders as per PDO or mysqli (or use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you wish to keep promoting outdated practices...)

See [Best way to stop SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php]) and [Prevent injection SQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309237/prevent-injection-sql-with-php) and [Can SQL injection be prevented with just addslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636926/can-sql-injection-be-prevented-with-just-addslashesstring)

Comment: Yes, there are solutions. Added useful links to other SO questions on the topic. The first link is particular good and shows a trivial example with PDO.

Comment: @Lucas Also look at the *negative answers* and comments in those links as well -- there is as much to be learned from those (not so good approaches) as the good answers.

Answer (score 2):

`htmlspecialchars` has *nothing* to do with MySQL. It's for escaping HTML special characters, characters that have special meaning when evaultated as **HTML**. You should use it before you write untrusted data to the browser, not to the database.

You need to remove `htmlspecialchars` entirely, and use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or better yet, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: So using mysql_real_escape_string is the only way, to be fully safe in this case? Also I don't need anything more?:)

Comment: @Lucas No. It's not the "only way". Read to the end of the sentence.

Comment: You can use `mysql_real_escape_string` as a drop-in replacement, but you *should* be using PDO.

Comment: Then if I'll switch to the PDO, then I can say I'm fully safe?:)
Also, how would it'll have to look like, if I'd be using PDO?

Comment: @Lucas Look. There is nothing you can do to say you're "fully safe", so stop asking after that. The fact that you're asking this stuff is a pretty good indication that you have no idea what you're doing. It's impossible for *experts* to make a non-trivial web app "fully safe", and they actually *know* what they're doing. Read the links in pst's answer, and then read some more, and then when you're done reading, go read some more. We can't tell you how to magically make your entire app secure with one function. Web security is an incredibly complex topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably unsafe, and you'd better use mysql_real_escape_string.