# does addslashes(stripslashes($field)) guarantee sql injection invulnerability?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, code-injection

Minus the whole addslashes() vs mysqli_real_escape_string() argumentation will stripping then adding slashes guarantee sql injection invulverability? Will this alter the data in anyway, for example displaying the string with double slashes after fetching it from the database?

Comment: The moment you accept input/data from external sources, **nothing** can guarantee **invulnerability**.

Comment: No: http://eleves.ec-lille.fr/~couprieg/post/Bypass-addslashes-with-UTF-8-characters

Comment: i am working in a framework with coding standards and I have a function that might have unescaped or escaped text coming in depending on who's calling it. I can't use mysql_real_escape_string for coding standard reasons.

Comment: This is just foolish, you're leaving the app is a vulnerable position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does mysql_real_escape_string() do that addslashes() doesn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534742/what-does-mysql-real-escape-string-do-that-addslashes-doesnt)

Answer (score 1):

Escaping characters (`addslashes()`) **may** protect you from SQL Injection.  I'm not an expert on how to sanitize inputs, and here's why:

I skipped the whole "sanitizing" thing and went straight to prepared statements.  Sanitizing / escaping means you have to do the reverse on the output side, which means double the effort every time, and **double the chances to mess up somewhere** - allowing bad input in.  If you just plop the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) between every database query you do and the database itself, your worries are over.

That's not to say, of course, that the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) protects you from attacks like CSRF or XSS, but the actual stored values are SQL-injection-safe, and you can strip html or whatever you need to do before you store it to protect from attacks like those.

Comment: As much as I'd like to I can't, use prepared statements. I'm just trying to find out if I have a string that I am unsure if it is escaped is the correct thing to do strip then slash or are there consequences to data integrity.

Answer (score 1):

so what you want to do is

```
$input='bla" SELECT * FROM blabla"';
$escaped=stripslashes(addslashes($input));
```

in that case

```
$input==$escaped is true
```

so no this would probably do nothing
thats why you should prefer mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: he did it the other way round which is not quite the same thing

Comment: I wrote this when the title was different and not as detailed

Answer (score 1):

NO
use: mysql_real_escape_string.

Why:  you are not considering a ton of issues, mainly encoding of strings, etc...

Comment: > Minus the whole addslashes() vs mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: regardless.  NO.  it won't guarantee anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, having the right amount of slashes helps with some vulnerabilities, but you still need to check user input. There is no guarantee sql injection invulnerability, ever.

Answer (score 0):

addslashes() will protect you in most cases. As for the getting the output, it depends how your submitting it, if you do

```
$input = addslashes("Bob's shoes")
```

you'll get Bob\'s shoes.

When you put this in your database

```
insert into tbl (txt) values (Bob\'s shoes)
```

The output of

```
select txt from tbl
```

will be Bob's shoes as you intended, the slashes are removed by the sql on insert.

If your anal about it you can say add other precautions, but if you want a quick and easy thing that's not a ridiculously secure website it should be fine. there's also built in php sanitize functions if you look them up