# how to insert HTML code into DB using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to update my database with new html code
this it the query:

```
UPDATE `Pages` SET `content`= '<div id="intro">
<div id="about" align="left">
<h2 class="bigHeader" dir="rtl"HEADER</h2>
<img src="img/Med-logo.png" alt="" />
<div id="wellcomePage" class="text-left text" dir="rtl">
<p>...some words....</p>
<p>.some words....</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>'
```

but all the time i get an error. 
how can i update my database, i don't know what will be inside this html code, is there a function that make all the code like string without special sign?

EDIT::
the problem is with the special char like ' i can't change the html code, is user chice  to put it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting html code in a mysql table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371093/inserting-html-code-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Also, sanitize the data (HTML) that is being inserted.

Comment: the error is because i have special chars inside the html code, i think

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do following using `addslashes()` function, so it will help easily to insert update html to

```
UPDATE `Pages` SET `content`= addslashes('<div id="intro">
<div id="about" align="left">
<h2 class="bigHeader" dir="rtl"HEADER</h2>
<img src="img/Med-logo.png" alt="" />
<div id="wellcomePage" class="text-left text" dir="rtl">
<p>...some words....</p>
<p>.some words....</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>')
```

Comment: but i need to add 'stripslashes' when i read back from the DB. THX

Comment: Yes. you have to add stripslashes when retrieve from DB.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:-
$htmlcode = mysql_real_escape_string($htmlcode);

For example:-

```
$htmlcode = '<div id="intro">
<div id="about" align="left">
<h2 class="bigHeader" dir="rtl"HEADER</h2>
<img src="img/Med-logo.png" alt="" />
<div id="wellcomePage" class="text-left text" dir="rtl">
<p>...some words....</p>
<p>.some words....</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>';

$htmlcode = mysql_real_escape_string($htmlcode);

UPDATE `Pages` SET `content`= '$htmlcode';
```

Answer (score 3):

store your html content in one variable and use addslashes() when you are inserting it to database.

```
$content='<div id="intro">
<div id="about" align="left">
<h2 class="bigHeader" dir="rtl"HEADER</h2>
<img src="img/Med-logo.png" alt="" />
<div id="wellcomePage" class="text-left text" dir="rtl">
<p>...some words....</p>
<p>.some words....</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>';
```

and write your query as below

```
UPDATE `Pages` SET `content`=addslashes($content);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this will do the trick

[Encode your text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

when you get the text back from the database just decode it back

Comment: hmm what is the type of column you are trying to enter the text to?

Answer (score 0):

This could be duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847567/inserting-html-into-database)

in any case... this could be the solution for you

```
$html = mysql_real_escape_string($html);
$sql = "UPDATE `Pages` SET `content`= $html";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a (') single Quote into your string.

You can use the 'htmlspecialchars' function with ENT_QUOTES as second argument.

And also 'mysql_real_escape_string' function can be used.

Like

```
$hcode = '<div id="intro">
<div id="about" align="left">
<h2 class="bigHeader" dir="rtl"HEADER</h2>
<img src="img/Med-logo.png" alt="" />
<div id="wellcomePage" class="text-left text" dir="rtl">
<p>...some words....</p>
<p>.some words....</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>';
$hcode = htmlspecialchars($hcode, ENT_QUOTES);
UPDATE `Pages` SET `content`= '$hcode';
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you could use PDO to prepare the statement before and then you would insert the data.
The variables you would insert can be anything, you do not need to care if they have ' or " or ' " > It is all fine, by using the prepare() we are saying that we will insert the following variables without any change. So even if you have code or sql injection it will consider as text no matter what.
You could do a PDO connection like this:

```
$host = 'hostname';
$user = 'duh_user';
$password = 'duh_pwd';
$dbname = 'myDatabase';

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8mb4';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$column1 = $htmlcode;
$column2 = $anything;
$column3 = $reallyAnything;

$query = "INSERT INTO table_name(column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$column1, $column2, $column3]);
```