# how to insert ms word text into database into html equivalent like in wordpress do

Tags: php

How to convert ms word text into html tag... ms word bullet shown as it is in database.. while I am checking this in wordpress, wordpress convert space into `&nbsp;` and bullet into `<ul><li>` but i need this function in my core php...

i am saving this ms word text into database:-

•Replace your toothbrush every three months.
•Interdental brushes come in various sizes. It may be helpful to ask your dentist or hygienist to show you the correct sizes for your mouth.

but same result is save in databse

while check this using wordpress, wordpress save this in database like

Replace your toothbrush every three months.

Interdental brushes come in various sizes. It may be helpful to ask your dentist or hygienist to show you the correct sizes for your mouth.

i want wordpress like result in my core php what can i do plz help

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631088/how-to-insert-html-code-into-db-using-php

Comment: @AmanKumar <li>Replace your toothbrush every three months.</li>
 <li>Interdental brushes come in various sizes. It may be helpful to ask your dentist or hygienist to show you the correct sizes for your mouth.</li> i need this typ of result.. i am using this function mysql_real_escape_string(); , also i am using htmlspecialchars($hcode, ENT_QUOTES); function but bullet [•] show instead of <li>

Answer (score 0):

You need what is called a rich text editor. You can look up tinyMCE for such purpose

EDIT

Then you need to do this

```
    $str = "<b>HI, I AM A PERSON</b>";
    $new_str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

So that will produce

```
    &lt;b&gt;HI, I AM A BOY&lt;/&gt;
```

Then to decode

```
    $str = "&lt;b&gt;HI, I AM A BOY&lt;/&gt;";
    $new_str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: ya but i want to filter it on server side in php

Answer (score 0):

**Try [Editors](http://ckeditor.com/features) to insert html into mysql**