# PHP/MySQL Injection example

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

This is a follow-up to this question: [Is PHP's addslashes vulnerable to sql injection attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339844/is-phps-addslashes-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-attack) (thanks to everyone that replied over there).

Same scenario, but I have this code (in another page):

```
             $ID = $_GET['id'];
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id='$ID'";
             $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

This should be easy enough to exploit, right?

If I remember correctly I CANNOT run a second query inside mysql_query() but I should be able to do some other malicious stuff, right?  Would love to be able to insert a user into the admin table or change a password or something, but I assume I wouldn't be able to do anything other than touch the blog table.  Is that correct?  Any suggestions on how I can play around and tweak something to prove that there are concerns?

Comment: Please avoid extraneous references to other questions.

Comment: @Marco - "mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)" (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Some (93!) interesting slides on [Advanced SQL Injection](http://www.slideshare.net/amiable_indian/advanced-sql-injection) on Slideshare.

Comment: this question smells. we have no proof that it is actually a security audit (performed by someone who have no idea on security at all)

Comment: @col - thats the exact reason i am here asking you guys.  i haven't done a security audit before, though i have done web development, and i have a client that has asked me to do update their site with best practices.  their request was that i show them a vulnerability.  i did a bunch of google research but was unable to come up with anything that would prove my point.  you guys gave me enough to do what i needed to do though, and i appreciate that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called `UNION` and allows you to pull from extra tables by using a second query.

I'm guessing something like `1' UNION ALL SELECT username title, password body FROM users WHERE '1'='1` would work. (pulls from the `users` table and maps the username and password values to their `blog` "equivalents").

Comment: UNION definitely helped.  I was unsure of the construct in this scenario, but I appreciate the nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think anyone would think you're trying to hack someone - this is a legitimate question.

You can't run a second query here, but you could do something malicious. For example if the query were an authentication query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password';
```

You could quite easily log in with `' OR 1 = 1` and gain access to the website.

Also, if the query was a DELETE or UPDATE query you could probably manipulate it to run without a WHERE clause.

Comment: Actually, you can run a second query.

Comment: "mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)" (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). If that's wrong, forgive me for going by what the PHP manual says.

Comment: You can use `UNION` - it's a SQL thing that allows you to execute multiple queries.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you counted that as a second query. I was talking about the classic SQL injection attack which most libraries make redundant now, in which you log in to a site with `'; DROP TABLE users; --`