# SQL WHERE condition depending on form input

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, where-clause

I have a form where the user can enter multiple months and my SQL query returns the data for those months.

For example, if the user enters January the SQL should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month = 'January'
```

If the user enters March, August, October the SQL should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (month = 'March' OR month = 'August' OR month = 'October')
```

How would I go about making the WHERE conditions dynamic like that because the user can enter however many months we wants? Its like an ad-hoc query. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Answer (score 2):

Create a comma-separated string from the array of months that are submitted and store it into variable $months. For example:

```
$form_months = array('September','November','December');
$months = join(',', $form_months);
```

Resulting in...

`'September','November','December'`

You can then use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE month IN (" . $months . ")";
```

Oh yeah.. and somebody said "beware SQL injections, blah, blah" - but that's you're call, not for me to wrap you in a user-safe cocoon for you to feel warm and cozy.

Comment: I sure wish we could delete other's comments. It is not my responsibility to purchase and advise the OP to wear a bullet-proof vest. If he chooses to do so with the K.I.S.S. answer I have provided, he is welcome to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using placeholders. Still.

What? Whoa, heck yeah! Still no worry about SQL injection (yay!) and the problem can be approached in nice little pieces - building the dynamic SQL and then binding the relevant value(s).

Imagine that we start with an array of data:

```
$stuff = array("January", "February");
```

Then we just need to create the appropriate template *with placeholders* dynamically, say:

```
.. WHERE (month = ? OR month = ?)
.. WHERE month IN (?, ?)           -- or
```

(The only thing we needed here was to know how many elements were in the array. These can be generated using a simple loop without actually caring about the values in the array! Should be simple to work out :-)

And then *bind the values from the array* [as shown in the (mysqli_stmt_bind) examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (e.g. use `call_user_func_array`). Also see [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) which provides a specific walk-through for this use case (note the named parameters).

Comment: You misspelled "Janurary" AND "Februrary"!

Comment: @DevlshOne I fail English :> Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

For PL/SQL, you can try the [IN](http://psoug.org/definition/IN.htm) clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month IN (/*list of months from user input*/);
```

I hope you're protecting against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Answer (score 0):

You may need pass the months as an array through `$_POST` or `$_GET`

For example consider that this is the part of the month in your html Form and you will submit it via POST

```
<input type="checkbox" name="month[]" value="January">January<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="month[]" value="February">February<br>
[...]
```

In your php processor you have this

```
$moth = isset($_POST['month']) ? $_POST['month'] : NULL;//get the array

if(!empty($month)){
 foreach ($month as $month_val) {
    $months_val[] = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$month_val). "'";
    //using mysqli
  //$dbcon is the conection parameter
 }
  $months_val_insert = implode(',', $months_val);    


  $month_values = $months_val_insert;


$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE month IN ($month_values )";
 }
```

This is the idea

Thanks to @user2246674 who point me out with this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534742/what-does-mysql-real-escape-string-do-that-addslashes-doesnt/16443803#16443803)

Comment: The word you're looking for there is "reference", not "referece".