# Why use mysql_real_escape_string, doesn't addslashes prevent everything?

Tags: php, security

I was looking through the docs and stumbled onto mysql_real_escape_string() and I'm not understanding why it's useful when you can just addslashes().  Can someone show me a scenario as to why it's useful?

I'm also curious why it requires a database connection.... that seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534742/what-does-mysql-real-escape-string-do-that-addslashes-doesnt , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91216/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-real-escape-string-and-addslashes , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162491/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string-without-connecting-to-db ...and some more.

Comment: @VolkerK yeah but he got a better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There is a great article about this here.](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) And this [discussion](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=337881) also points out the pros and cons of each solution.

> addslashes() was from the developers
>   of PHP whereas
>   mysql_real_escape_string uses the
>   underlying MySQL C++ API (i.e. from
>   the developers of MySQL).
>   mysql_real_escape_string escapes EOF
>   chars, quotes, backslashes, carriage
>   returns, nulls, and line feeds. There
>   is also the charset aspect.

Comment: +1 for the link to Shiflett's site, just what I would have posted.

Comment: -1 That "great article"  is very old and that has been patched.  Try it for your self.

Answer (score 2):

Nether mysql_real_escape_string()  or addslashes()  prevent everything (what about xss or even xsrf?),  and most importantly nether of them prevent all SQL Injection.

For instance this code is vulnerable to sql injection:

```
mysql_query("select * from user where id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id]));
```

Exploit:

```
http://localhost/test.php?id=1 or sleep(50)
```

patch:

```
mysql_query("select * from user where id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id])."'");
```

Use parametrized queries with either ADODB or PDO,  this is the only bullet proof sql injection protection.

Comment: What do you mean ADODB or PDO ?