# Need PHP HTML help with register form

Tags: php, html, forms, registration

here is some code that I plan on using in a registration form for my site

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("includes/config.php");
if ($Authenticated == False) {
    ?>
    <div id="register">
        <form action="index.php?page=register" method="post">
            <lable id="registerStuff"> Name: </>
                <input id="registerIn" type='text' name='name' maxlength="20" />
                <br/>
                <lable id="registerStuff"> Surname: </>
                    <input id="registerIn" type='text' name='surname' maxlength="20" />
                    <br/>
                    <lable id="registerStuff"> Username: </>
                        <input id="registerIn" type='text' name='username' maxlength="20" />
                        <br/>
                        <lable id="registerStuff"> Password: </>
                            <input id="registerIn" type='password' name='password' maxlength="20" />
                            <br/>
                            <lable id="registerStuff"> Retype Password: </>
                                <input id="registerIn" type='password' name='passwordcheck' maxlength="20" />
                                <br/>
                                <input type='submit' value='Register'>
                                <br/>
                                </form>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
                                $surname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
                                $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                                $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
                                $passwordcheck = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['passwordcheck']));
                                if ($username OR $password OR $passwordcheck != null) {
                                    if ($password == $passwordcheck) {
                                        $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, username, password) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $username . "', '" . $password . "')";
                                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                                        if (!$result) {
                                            echo "Username wrong";
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        echo "passwords didnt match";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if ($Authenticated == True) {
                                header("Location: index.php");
                            }
                            ?>
```

I cant seem to get proper error messages working, I need to check if the 2 passwords entered are identical, I also need to make sure that no blanks can be entered into the DB. If anyone could help me at all it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made quite a common mistake I guess. Most beginners seem to want to write as little code as possible. However, in this case that doesn't work. You will have to check each variable for emptiness.

Your code would be correct when you changed your if construct:

```
if ($username != "" AND $password != "" AND $passwordcheck != "") {

}
```

However, to make the code look a bit slighter, it's probably best to just use the function `empty()` that returns **TRUE** if the variable is empty:

```
if (!empty($username) AND !empty($password) AND !empty($passwordcheck)) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is my overall system a bad/unsafe one?

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting code you have there. I would suggest, before asking people here to write more than half of your script, to Google "PHP Login Script" - [`this`](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html) is the number one result and the answer to  your question.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name 
     WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

With that said, this is the incorrect way of doing it and you should look into prepared statements. Since you're starting off, you probably should start of with a security mindset.

Comment: Thanks, ill keep reading and researching, but just out of interest, why is this the incorrect way? is it not safe?

Comment: It's not safe at all. Leaves you site open for SQL injection.

Comment: If I added this in?   $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

Comment: $name = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));         is that safer?

Comment: Here is a good question that will address what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540441/why-use-mysql-real-escape-string-doesnt-addslashes-prevent-everything

Comment: You're welcome, remember to close this question out if you are finished.