# mysql_real_escape_string VS addslashes

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone shed some light on the differences between these 2 functions, from the PHP manual:

`addslashes`:
Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in database queries etc. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).

`mysql_real_escape_string`:
`mysql_real_escape_string()` calls MySQL's library function `mysql_real_escape_string`, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, , ', " and \x1a.

From what I gather the major difference is \x00, \n \r \x1a which `addslashes` doesn't escape, can you tell me what the significance of that is?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you quote is probably from the doc, but as far as I know it's not necessarily true.

`addslashes` adds slashes to characters that are commonly disturbing. `mysql_real_escape_string` escapes whatever MySQL needs to be escaped. This may be more or less characters than what `addslashes` takes care of.

Also, `mysql_real_escape_string` will not necessarily add slashes to escape. While I think it works if you do it that way, recent versions of MySQL escape quotes by putting two of them together instead of by putting a slash before it.

I believe you should always use your data provider's escape function instead of `addslashes`, because `addslashes` may either do too much or not enough work for the purpose you use it. On the other hand, `mysql_real_escape_string` *knows* what to do to prepare a string for embedding it in a query. Even if the specs change about how to escape stuff and suddenly it's not backslashes that you should use anymore, your code will still work because `mysql_real_escape_string` will be aware of it.

Comment: ANSI SQL specifies that a single quote can be represented by two single quotes in a row, but mysql_real_escape_string() doesn't do that -- it always escapes using a backslash as far as I have seen. If you have an example of a version of MySQL that escapes by doubling the quote character, I'd be interested in seeing the example.

Comment: @BillKarwin, PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string` calls MySQL's [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html), which does whatever it wants to escape the strings. The PHP documentation now says that it uses blackslashes, but the MySQL documentation says nothing about that. I do remember that at some point it would escape with `''` instead of `\'`, maybe that's not the case anymore, or maybe it requires specific connection settings (`mysql_real_escape_string` takes a connection argument so it can check them after all).

Comment: Aha, I tested and found out that if you set `SQL_MODE=NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` it behaves like you describe. My confusion was because `mysqldump` still doesn't do the double-quote characters even if you have that sql mode set. Which means you could create a dump file that can't be reimported on the server that generated it!

Answer (score 17):

mysql_real_escape_string() also takes into account the character set used by the current connection to the database.

The PHP function mysql_real_escape_string() uses the MySQL C API function of the same name: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Also read [addslashes() Versus mysql_real_escape_string()](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) by noted PHP security expert Chris Shiflett, for a demonstration that you can get SQL injection exploits even if you use addslashes().

---

Other folks recommend using query parameters, and then you don't have to do any escaping of dynamic values.  I recommend this too, but in PHP you'd have to switch to PDO or ext/mysqli, because the plain ext/mysql API doesn't support query parameters.

Also there may be some corner cases where you can't use query parameters for a dynamic string value, like your search pattern in a fulltext search.

Comment: +1 for reading material.  It's good to be informed about these topics.

Comment: "have to swtich to PDO" sounds like a benefit to me!

Comment: @Tom: Yeah, I prefer PDO and I do recommend it.  But if a project already has lots of code using ext/mysql, it's hard to justify the time to rewrite it all.

Comment: I just started rewriting my DB wrapper to use PDO, if you app deals with critical user data then IMHO it's worth it for the peace of mind. I can't trust myself to always remember to use mysql_real_escape_string...

Answer (score 1):

There was a bunch of history with `mysql_escape_string` and `mysql_real_escape_string`. They were both attempts at providing a "general" escaping mechanism that would minimize the probability of sql injection attacks.

`mysql_real_escape_string` and `addslashes` are ok, if they're what you really need --  but they probably aren't.

As @afrazier says, you should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of prepare quer"ies using PDO you can use this while your application uses MySQLi (beware! "i" at and of Mysql")

```
$nick = $connect->real_escape_string($nick);
$nick= addcslashes($nick, '%_');

$pass = $connect->real_escape_string($pass);
$pass = addcslashes($pass, '%_');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore both and just use parameterized queries. Unless, of course, you like injection attacks.

Comment: For completeness, could you reference the functions/classes to switch to?  I come from a Postgres background so I know to use ps_ functions or PDO, but I don't know what supports parametrized queries for a MySQL user.

Comment: Consistent usage of `mysql_real_escape_string` will prevent injection attacks.

Comment: Vague generalizations aren't very helpful.

Comment: @Ryan Tenney: Escaping is not a full solution to prevent injection attacks.  See my presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies

Comment: @Tom: You can use PDO for MySQL as well as one can use it for PostgreSQL.  @Bill Karwin: Thanks for the link.  That's useful to have.

Comment: @Bill: That's a great presentation, thanks for sharing! I should have been more clear and specified that escaping won't help in some situations, but your presentation covers that in more depth than one could here in a comment.