# What's the difference between PHP's addslashes and mysql(i)_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, security, mysql-real-escape-string, addslashes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_real_escape_string VS addslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473047/mysql-real-escape-string-vs-addslashes)

If they don't do exactly the same, what's the difference? The delimiter for values inside a MySQL query is the `'` isn't it? Or maybe the `"` but that's also escaped with addslashes.

In other database engines I understand (and definitely inside a db wrapper like PDO), but why are so many people so adament on using mysql(i)_escape_string instead of addslashes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all: **do not use `mysql_escape_string`, it is deprecated (for a reason)!**

If you have to support a legacy application that connects to the database through the `mysql` extension (which [has been deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)), use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) instead. Otherwise [switch immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) to `mysqli`, where prepared statements and bound parameters provide a more robust mechanism for escaping user input.

That said, the answer can be found by reading the description of [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

**Difference #1**

`addslashes` does not know anything about MySql connection encodings. If you pass it a string containing bytes representing an encoding other than the encoding used by the MySql connection, it will happily escape *all bytes having the values of the characters* `'`, `"`, `\` and `\x00`. This may not be the same as *all the characters* `'`, `"`, `\` and `\x00` if you are using an encoding other than 8-bit encodings and UTF-8. The result will be that the string received by MySql will be corrupted.

To trigger this bug, try using [`iconv`](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert your variable to UTF-16 and then escape it with `addslashes`. See what your database receives.

This is one reason why `addslashes` should not be used for escaping.

**Difference #2**

In contrast to `addslashes`, `mysql_real_escape_string` also escapes the characters `\r`, `\n`, and `\x1a`. It appears that these characters have to be escaped as well when talking to MySql, otherwise a malformed query may be the result

This is the other reason why `addslashes` should not be used for escaping.

Comment: I did mean mysql_real_escape_string. My bad. Very clear answer!

Answer (score 5):

[Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) demonstrates a real world case where escaping SQL using `addslashes()` fails, and `mysql_real_escape_string()` is the only way to go.

> How does this help? If I want to
> attempt an SQL injection attack
> against a MySQL database, having
> single quotes escaped with a backslash
> is a bummer. If you're using
> addslashes(), however, I'm in luck.
> All I need to do is inject something
> like 0xbf27, and addslashes() modifies
> this to become 0xbf5c27, a valid
> multi-byte character followed by a
> single quote. In other words, I can
> successfully inject a single quote
> despite your escaping. That's because
> 0xbf5c is interpreted as a single
> character, not two. Oops, there goes
> the backslash.
>
> ....
>
> Despite the use of addslashes(), I'm able to log in successfully without knowing a valid username or password. I can simply exploit the SQL injection vulnerability.
>
> To avoid this type of vulnerability, use mysql_real_escape_string(), prepared statements, or any of the major database abstraction libraries.

now this is admittedly a rare  edge case, but a demonstration of why people are so adamant about using the database specific escape functions. **Only the database library can know for sure what kind of escaping is needed.** Different wrappers, character sets and SQL flavours (like MS SQL server) need different escaping. Ignoring that fact is how vulnerabilities are born.

Comment: `addslashes()` is a glorified wrapper to what amounts to `str_replace($var, "'", "\\'")`, while `mysql_real_escape_string()` calls the actual MySQL API function that does escaping, and does the job properly.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical in that you should be using neither of them, because you should be using placeholders rather than building SQL from untrusted data.

See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for how to do it the right way.

Comment: Placeholders to replace with **what**? Something a db layer does? And what do you think the db layer does? Use some kind of mysql_real_escape_string I assume...

Answer (score 0):

It's foremost a charset issue. What `addslashes()` does would be sufficient for escaping data intermixed with SQL commands, if the data was purely **ASCII**. But besides UTF-8 encoding variations, MySQL in some configuration also allows fringe charsets like UCS2 (UTF-16) or GB/Big5 chinese charsets. There it's insufficient to just escape the raw ascii code of `'` into `\'`. And then the MySQL way of escaping strings was never very much SQL-standards-compliant to begin with. It might be deprecated in future releases of the MySQL server.