# change \ to \\ for path php

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a string which is a path and is a variable in which I have to save in my database. But the path is

```
C:\foldera\folderb\folder1\folder2
```

and obviously I need it to be

```
C:\\foldera\\folderb\\folder1\\folder2
```

for the insertion in database of mysql.

Please help me find the solution. I tried `str_replace` but it won't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your prepared statement should do this :-)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: please if you can give me some hints. I have no idea what to search for and I need it to continue my project.

Comment: use regexp to do a search and replace...

Comment: His question is how to escape backslashes not prevent SQL injection attacks. However it is a helpful link to point him to.

Comment: For paths in PHP, just use forward slashes. They work fine, even on Windows platforms - the PHP engine converts them.

Answer (score -1):

The function you are looking for is `addslashes($string);` This function adds the slashes to turn your string into the string you are looking for. But if you are planning on using it as a parameter in an SQL statment you want to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Also use single quotes in the string in order for `addslashes()` to work properly. double quotes will parse it as \f not just '\'.

Comment: No, it's not. [What's the difference between PHP's addslashes and mysql(i)\_escape\_string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4486016)

Comment: I need to change '\' to '\\' do you have any idea how please?

Comment: @Adnama: No, you don't need to change '\' to '\\'.  You need to learn how to SQL-escape a string, or use parameters.

Comment: No because when I used it with one slash, the database saved it as 1 string, and ignored the slashes. and it saved it as :

Comment: C:folderafolderbfolder1folder2

Comment: are you using double quotes or single quotes

Comment: I am using:  

$_SESSION['currentPath'] = getcwd();
$curpath=$_SESSION['currentPath'];
$path = $curpath.'\\'.$newpath;
INSERT INTO file (`id`,`path`)VALUES(('$id','$path');

Please help