# How do i secure this PHP script?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

I'm worried about sql injection, so how do i prevent it?
I'm using this script but have had several people tell me its very insecure, if anyone can help by telling me how it would be great :).

source code:

```
if(isset($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
$lastmsg=$_POST['lastmsg'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE item_id<'$lastmsg' ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 16");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$msg_id=$row['item_id'];
$message=$row['item_content'];
```

Comment: Is `$lastmsg` a numeric value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never, ever, put information from the user (`$_POST` or `$_GET`) directly into a query. If they are numbers, always convert them to integers first with `(int)$var` or `intval($var)`; if they are strings, always escape them with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Read https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string and use it.

Comment: **Note:** Make sure you use `mysql_real_escape_string` NOT `mysql_escape_string`

Answer (score 2):

```
$lastmsg = intval($_POST['lastmsg']);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in this case. A check for a failed `intval` would be nice though, otherwise it will default to `0` which can have unintended consequences

Comment: Feel free to edit :) Thanks for suggestions. Yes, he should check if it is > 0.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is migrating to mysqli_ or PDO and using prepared statements for your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this :

```
$lastmsg=addslashes($_POST['lastmsg']);
```

for a larger scale you can use a more robust solution here is the function you can use

```
function escape_value($value) {
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");
    if ($new_php){
        if ($magic_quotes_active){
            $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    } else {
        if(!$magic_quotes_active) { $value = addslashes($value); }
    }
    return trim($value);
}
```

mysql_real_escape_string is not always available so here is a work around

Comment: `addslashes` is not the right choice. You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to be protected from injection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473047/mysql-real-escape-string-vs-addslashes

Comment: Quoting the PHP documentation: "It's highly recommended to use DBMS specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL)"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive is disabled in your PHP configuration (PHP.ini).

If lastmsg is a string and you are using mysql, do this:

```
$lastmsg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastmsg']);
```

If lastmsg is a string and your DBMS does not have a native escape function, do this:

```
$lastmsg = addslashes($_POST['lastmsg']);
```

If lastmsg should be a number, check for that instead and don't do any escaping. You can use function [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and then cast the numeric string to an integer using [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).