# How to make this PHP/SQL code safer? 

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm wondering how I can make this code safer, I'm using it as login.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) and isset($_POST["password"])) {
if($_POST["username"] == $adminusr && $_POST["password"] == $adminpass){
```

I want to make it a little more safe to prevent sql-injections and such. Do you have any ideas ? I'd like to learn more about making safer sites.

Thank you dudes and dudettes

Edit:

Sorry I didn't post all the code needed, but here is the complete code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../include/config.php");

if(isset($_POST["username"]) and isset($_POST["password"])) {
if($_POST["username"] == $adminusr && $_POST["password"] == $adminpass){

    $_SESSION['admin_user'] = $adminusr;
    $_SESSION['admin_password'] = $adminpass;
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

}else if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']=='out') {
unset($_SESSION['admin_user']);
unset($_SESSION['admin_password']);
session_destroy (); 

}

if($_SESSION['admin_user'] == $adminusr && $_SESSION['admin_password'] == $adminpass){
$_SESSION['testdd'] = 'test';
header("location:index.php");
exit;
}

?>
```

Thank you once again :)

Comment: I don't see anything SQL related in this code at all.

Comment: Sorry about that, here it is =)

Comment: There's still nothing SQL related in there. Where does $adminusr and $adminpass come from?

Comment: it comes from config.php where it says: $adminusr = "xxxx"; and $adminpass = "xxxx";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **are** using `$_POST['username']` in a query the following code will keep you save from SQL-injection.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users 
          WHERE users.username = '$username' 
          AND users.Passhash = SHA2(CONCAT(users.id,'$password'),512) ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
....
```

Note that you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` with `mysql_query`
and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with `mysqli_query`.

Even better is to use PDO with php5, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

**Handling passwords in MySQL**
Note that is strongly recommended not to store passwords in the clear in your database.
Always store a hash (preferably using SHA2) in your database and use a salt.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hash+salt+mysql
For more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape special characters (assuming you are querying database). E.g. `$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);`. Otherwise, it seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show what you are actually doing with the database.

If you use a regular mysql_query, you need to encode unwanted characters, quotes (",') for example.

You also need to keep in mind, that people might want these characters in their passwords, so you need to store them in the DB encoded in some way.

Probably an MD5 hash, or just regular entity encoding (see below).

```
htmlentities($pass,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')


(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? mysql_real_escape_string($item):$item;
```

You should still use variable binding, that helps avoiding any SQL injections.

[Check out this introduction to PDO, its really useful.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help but some of this is borderline bad advice the way you say it. For instance, filtering out " and ' is not an acceptable solution but escaping it certainly is. So you have it partially correct

Comment: Sorry if it was not understandable, by filtering out, I meant not putting it straight into a query...

Answer (score 1):

I think you code should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) and isset($_POST["password"])) {
$handle = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mtsql_select_db($db, $handle);
$query = "SELECT user FROM table_users WHERE user='{$_POST["username"]}' AND password=MD5('{$_POST["password"]}')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $handle);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
 {
```

What you need here is to escape special charcarter using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [PDO prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection), so we change this:

```
$input["user"] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$input["password"] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$query = "SELECT user FROM table_users WHERE user='{$input["user"]}' AND password=MD5('{$input["password"]}')";
.
.
.
```

You may also use addslashes() function, but it may be [sufficient enough](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string), I am quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473047/mysql-real-escape-string-vs-addslashes):

> addslashes adds slashes to characters
>   that are commonly disturbing.
>   mysql_real_escape_string escapes
>   whatever MySQL needs to be escaped.
>   This may be more or less characters
>   than what addslashes takes care of.