# how to update HTML code into a MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql, xml

PHP Version: 5.3.19
MYSQL Version: 5.0.96

I have a database table with a field that contains xml data:

XML DATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <book>
        <page>
            <data>Page 1</data>
        </page>
        <page>
            <data>Page 2</data>
        </page>
        <page>
            <data>Page 3</data>
        </page>
    </book>
```

I have successfully had the xml data displayed, now I'm trying to update it with php

PHP CODE:

```
$id = 1;
    $fav_id = $id;
    $userid = 1;
    $data_update = '<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: xx-large;"><em><strong>Title</strong></em></span></p>';
    $page_number = 0;

    mysql_select_db($database_main, $main);
    $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id = $id";
    $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $main) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
    $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

    $xmldata = (string)$row_Recordset1['projectData'];
    $parsed = simplexml_load_string($xmldata);
    $data = $parsed->xpath('//data');
        $data[$page_number] = $data_update;

    $x = 0;
    $array_length = count($data);
    while($x < $array_length){
            if($x==0){
                $finalData .= '<?xml version="1.0"?><book>';
            }
            $finalData .= "<page><data>$data[$x]</data></page>";
            if($x==$array_length-1){
                $finalData .= "</book>";    
            }
            $x++;

    }
    $FinalData = mysql_real_escape_string($finalData);
        $updateSQL = "UPDATE projects SET projectData=$finalData  WHERE id=$fav_id";
        mysql_select_db($database_main, $main);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $main) or die(mysql_error());
```

I want the end result to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <book>
        <page>
            <data>
                <p style="text-align: center;">
                    <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: xx-large;">
                        <em><strong>Title</strong></em>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </data>
        </page>
        <page>
            <data>Page 2</data>
        </page>
        <page>
            <data>Page 3</data>
        </page>
    </book>
```

although when i try `addslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` i get:

DATA:

```
<p center;\\\"="" style="\\\"text-align:">
    <span xx-large;\\\"="" font-size:="" underline;="" style="\\\"text-decoration:">
        <em>
            <strong>Title</strong>
        </em>
    </span>
</p>
```

my question is why are those two functions [`addslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`] giving me the result above, and how do I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `addslashes()` pretty much do the exact same thing with `mysql_real_escape_string()` adding that little bit extra.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on `mysql_real_escape_string()`

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on `add_slashes()`

> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in database queries etc. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash (\) and NUL (the NULL byte).

To stop this from happening, there's not much you can do, just use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) when outputting the field.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_real_escape_string VS addslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473047/mysql-real-escape-string-vs-addslashes)
I hope this gives you answer of addslashes() and mysql_real_escape_string().. I can't post a comment.. I know this is not complete answer for your question. That can clear your doubts regarding the usage. addslashes Is GENERIC function for every character that requires "\" and mysql_real_escape_string is MySQL specific!