# character escaping and hashing functions

Tags: php, mysqli

We've all read about protecting from SQL injection attacks: [How Can I Prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), [SQL Injection Attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), [PHP: mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), [How to prevent code injection attacks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205889/how-to-prevent-code-injection-attacks-in-php/1206461#1206461) as well as many others concerning the "debate" of [php - mysql_real_escape_string vs addslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473047/mysql-real-escape-string-vs-addslashes).

However, I'm curious about the proper way to protect my SQL statements when utilizing a function on data before passing it to the database. Must I `addslashes()` and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` the values before passing them to a function such as `crypt()` which then would be used in a *prepared* statement, utilizing `bind_param()`? Can I forego the `addslashes()` and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` because the value eventually goes into a *prepared* statement?

Comment: _Can I forego the addslashes() and mysqli_real_escape_string() because the value eventually goes into a prepared statement?_ YES and is the way you should be doing it.

Comment: Agreed - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36628423/1301332 answers my question. Mark as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference which particular kind of data is going to database or what was the treatment for it. For the SQL query the process should be all the same