# Is there a Limit on MySQL IN() list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, quickbooks

I have about 273 items in a MySQL IN() list, and I believe this is causing a problem with getting all of the information I need for these items, and not sure how to change this query to just 1 or atleast less than 273 individual queries.  Basically I have a list of string names that I need to query against and get the `Name` and `ListID` where Name is inside of a 273 count array:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT Name, ListID
    FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'quickbook_items
    WHERE Name IN ("' . implode('", "', array_map('addslashes', $part_names)) . '")
    ORDER BY NULL', ARRAY_A);
```

I feel like I have read somewhere that using queries in Wordpress with `IN` could be problematic if the list is too large, in that Wordpress will not grab all data.  But I don't remember if this is a Wordpress `$wpdb` limitation or a MySQL limitation.  In any case, I am NOT getting all of the 273 rows returned, so I'm really not sure how to perform this query, while keeping db hits lower than 273 times (which would occur if I put the query inside of a loop, looping through `$part_names`.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to query Name and ListID from the `quickbook_items` table as shown above?  Could really use some help here, or if there is a way to not have a limit of characters on a query set, to achieve this?

Comment: stackoverflow says [no limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275640/mysql-in-condition-limit) in mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL IN condition limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275640/mysql-in-condition-limit)

Comment: use LOWER() or UPPER() function to match name. may be case issue. or issue like maxlee's = maxlee\'s

Comment: Offtopic: you'll probably not want use addslashes, but mysqli_real_escape_string or Pdo::quote .
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473047/mysql-real-escape-string-vs-addslashes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

addslashes() is not suitable for true escaping for MySQL (for example hexadecimal representation might be used)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `IN` clause and `max_allowed_packet`

There's no defined limit on the *number* of items within `IN (...)`.

However, the length of the SQL string itself (in bytes) is limited by the value of the `max_allowed_packet` system variable.

Here an excerpt from the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value.

The default value of [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is 4 MB, so unless you had changed this value, it's extremely unlikely that this is the problem. 
Besides, hitting this limit would have caused an error rather than wrong results.

---

## `addslashes`

It's really not a good idea to use `addslashes` to build MySQL string literals. 
Consider using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for this purpose.

---

## A suggestion

Could you please do the following to analyze the issue. 
Build a loop over `$part_names`, and execute the very same statement (incl. `implode`) - but for just one name in every iteration. Then check whether every iteration returns a non-empty result.

This way you would get the names which aren't returned and it can give you some clues.

Another possible outcome would be that *all names are returned* - in this case the problem could indeed be with the number of items within the `IN` clause.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood, but this seems different from the sql injection prevention recommended by WordPress themselves. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Comment: Wordpress adds magic quotes even if you have it turned off in php.  `addslashes` is important for this feature which is only available to the Wordpress Administrators anyways and that would be a total of 2 people.

Comment: I thought I remember reading that the Wordpress class `$wpdb` functions puts a limit on the total number of characters allowed inside of these functions.  A co-worker of mine has even confirmed this for me before.

Comment: Ok, guys, it seems that wpengine is killing the query as it is too long in characters (this is ridiculous):  https://wpengine.com/support/troubleshoot-wordpress-wp-engine-error-log/#killedquery

Comment: I am currently in the process of moving all of my sites out of the wpengine outrageous prices and limitations.